# One array, multiple types

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion

I have a array which is FIFO list and which I am adding my data records to.
My data record can be of any of the standard types (string, char, int, long, unsigned, float, double) which i push to my array using a function.
I want to later read that data record in order they were added.

This is what i have tried:

```
class List
{
    typedef std::pair<typename, std::vector<char>> Record; // typename ??

    public:
        template <typename T>
        void addRecord(T value)
        {
            char* arr = reinterpred_cast<char*>(&value);  // Casting ?
            // Convert to Record and push to _records
        }

        template <typename T>
        T getRecord(std::vector<Record>::iterator record) const
        {
            // Convert Record to T and return 
        }

    private:
        std::vector<Record> _records;
}
```

How to convert from those type to byte array or is there any other way to do this ?

Example way i want to use this:

```
List list;
list.addRecord("Test string");
list.addRecord(10);
list.addRecord(999999);
list.addRecord("Test string 2");
list.addRecord('X');
...
```

And then read them the same way:

```
std::string testString = list.getRecord(...);
char testChar = list.getRecord(...);
int testInt = list.getRecord(...);
....
```

Comment: `string` is not a basic type that'll survive this sort of treatment, in general. Why don't you use `boost::variant`?

Comment: boost is a thing in that case but I am sorry I forgot to mention that one of my project requirements is to use only standard libraries.

Comment: @user3065410 - `std::string` will not work given this setup.  Also, if the list has 100 items in it, what type will item 35 be?  I'm asking this rhetorically, because there is a big hole in your design, and that is it will be a pain to remember what each type in this list of yours is.

Comment: `boost::any` is another option, and if you want to avoid using `boost`, it's not hard to build it yourself: there are numerous variants available, e.g. [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48250/39083) (simple version) or [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48344/39083) (more advanced version).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, you are right I have understood it now my idea isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @iavr - I had a quite long brainstorm now and I got to point that what I am trying to achive isn't worth so much effort. The union idea as suggested below is very interesting and I think that's it fits here very well since there is a very tight set of types that I want to support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are restricted to using only the standard library you will need to either implement a solution yourself or use an existing easily adaptable solution. What you are looking for is referred to as a [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) or variant. This is a data structure that contains a `union` to hold multiple types of data at the same location *and* a separate value outside of the union to indicate which element is active/used.

For integral types this is fairly each to manage as you only have to provide primitive support for setting and retrieving the value. For more complex types like `std::string` and `std::vector` things get a little more difficult if you are not using C++11. This is because prior to C++11 a `union` cannot contain types that have either a non-trivial copy constructor, a non-trivial destructor, or a non-trivial copy-assignment operator.

Both of the example `any` classes provided in the comments ([here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48250/39083) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48344/39083)) seem to be reasonable and complete implementations but require C++11. Both rely only on components in the standard library so they may be viable solutions for you. However if you are not using C++11 or need a simpler solution to base your solution on I have provided a sample below. It handles `char`, `int`, and `double` types so if you need to support more complex types you'll need to add them. In the case of complex types (and no C++11) you will need to hold a pointer to the instance and manage the lifetime yourself (either manually or with a smart pointer). You will also need to handle copying and assignment based on your specific needs (deep vs. shallow copies).

Simple tagged union:

```
struct TaggedUnion
{
    enum Type
    {
        Char,
        Int,
        Double
    };


    TaggedUnion(const char& value) : type(Char), value(value) {}
    TaggedUnion(const int& value) : type(Int), value(value) {}
    TaggedUnion(const double& value) : type(Double), value(value) {}

    Type getType() const { return type; }
    char getChar() const { assert(type == Char); return value.getChar(); }
    int getInt() const { assert(type == Int);  return value.getInt(); }
    double getDouble() const { assert(type == Double);  return value.getDouble(); }


private:

    union Union
    {
        Union(const char& value) : charValue(value) {}
        Union(const int& value) : intValue(value) {}
        Union(const double& value) : doubleValue(value) {}

        char getChar() const { return charValue; }
        int getInt() const { return intValue; }
        double getDouble() const { return doubleValue; }

    private:

        char    charValue;
        int     intValue;
        double  doubleValue;
    };

    Type type;
    Union value;
};
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::vector<TaggedUnion> values;

    values.push_back(TaggedUnion(0.0));    //  Store double/float
    values.push_back(TaggedUnion(0));       //  Store int
    values.push_back(TaggedUnion(' '));     //  Store char
}
```

Comment: This looks like an excellent idea ! I went in really, really wrong direction as I never though of using unions in there. It seems to solve all my problems and as I am using C++11 and as you said, non-trivial types such as string are also supported which is perfect !

Answer (score 0):

Using a union, like suggested in another answer, is the most direct solution. As an alternative, I would like to suggest an approach that I think is much more object oriented. The idea is to define a abstract base class for your values, which defines all operations you need for the values, and then a derived class for each type of value:

```
class Value {
public:
    virtual ~Value() {}

    // Define operations needed for values, e.g.
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class IntValue: public Value {
public:
    IntValue(int val) : m_val(val) {}

    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << m_val;
    }

private:
    int m_val;
};

class StringValue: public Value {
public:
    StringValue(const std::string& val) : m_val(val) {}

    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << m_val;
    }

private:
    std::string m_val;
};

// Equivalent class definitions for other value types.
```

Then, to build a collection of values:

```
std::vector<Value*> values;
values.push_back(new IntValue(42));
values.push_back(new StringValue("Hello"));
```

One thing to be careful about is that the container contains pointers, and the values are dynamically allocated. This means that the values are not automatically freed when the container is destroyed. So you will have to either manually delete the elements when the container is destroyed, or use some form of smart pointers instead of naked pointers as the type stored in the container.

The main benefit is that you don't have a single class that deals with all possible types. Instead, they are nicely isolated. For example, you can add support for a new type by simply implementing a new class, without changing any existing code.

Comment: Strongly disagree.  This is a perfect example of a bad "religious" OOP design.  Now, whenever you want to add some new functionality on the receiving end of the queue, you have to add it as a method on every class.  If you ever want to actually get a hold of the underlying data, you still have to implement something like a tagged union anyway.  This design makes the queue bleed into to other parts of the system that shouldn't need to know about it.

Comment: Union version sticks better to me as I think it provides more consistency.

Comment: @japreiss It really depends on the specific case. As long as you really just need to store basic types, I wouldn't use this. But on the more generic topic of how to store multiple types in an array, which is the title of the question, it's worth presenting both options. In most real world cases, this is the more scalable approach.